# Sharing session between two website applications on same solution and domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am running two websites in parallel on the same solution, both running on Local IIS, the main on `domain/` the other on `domain/api`.

The user is connected in the web forms application (domain/) then I need to authorize him on `domain/api` but although there is no CORS and the session_id in the sent headers are the same, the api doesn't recognize the session (written there is no data in `HttpContext.Current.Session`, `count = 0`), while the web forms project recognizes.

To enable session in web api I added `HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required)` under `Application_PostAuthorizeRequest` in `Global.asax`.

Comment: Why would you want client and web service to share session? If they're meant to work as a single app - simple make webservice into a class. Otherwise if API is meant to be a real API - it will never see remote client session

Comment: Its an old website that part of it is upgraded now with api, i have no choice. the user is saved in session.

Answer (score 0):

if you really need to do it this way, you can try saving the session objects in the database and write a token on a cookie that points to those session values, since you said they are on the same domain, both apps can access the cookie and retrieve the token and fetch the values you need from the database where you stored using that token id. I did it the same way once when i have to make modifications on an old system just like you do. Works great and you can pin it on the wall fast.

Comment: It doesnt really answer to my question, I'm trying to get the session, but with no success.